# How to access cart details or session id in commerce promotion condition

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have created a new condition for a promotion in our Sitecore Commerce site following this [example](http://blog.alpha-solutions.us/2018/01/how-to-create-a-custom-condition-in-sitecore-commerce-8-2-1/).
Is it possible to get cart details or the session id inside the evaluate method?

The evaluate method is triggered when  user clicks on the 'apply promo' button in UI.

```
namespace Sitecore.Feature.Commerce.Promotions.Engine.Conditions
{
    using Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data;
    using Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Carts;
    using Sitecore.Framework.Rules;
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Configuration;


    [EntityIdentifier("Future Event Dates")]
    public class FutureEventDatesCondition : ICartsCondition, ICondition, IMappableRuleEntity
    {
        public IRuleValue<string> FutureEventStartDate { get; set; }
        public IRuleValue<string> FutureEventEndDate { get; set; }

        public bool Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
        {
           //how to get the cartid or sessionid in here           
        }
    }
}
```

We are using Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@RobEarlam from slack helped me with the solution.

The cart details can be accessed like this inside the `Evaluate` method.

```
public bool Evaluate(IRuleExecutionContext context)
{
  CommerceContext commerceContext = context.Fact<CommerceContext>((string)null);
  List<Cart> lstCarts = commerceContext.GetObjects<Cart>();
  Cart cart = lstCarts[0];
}
```